# Python logging with a library (namespaced packages)

Tags: python, logging

My project consists of a number of namespaced packages and I want to set up logging properly for them: they are meant to be used as a library by other "frontends".

Suppose I have the case, for package foo.xyz:

```
 foo/
      __init__.py
      xyz/
          __init__.py
         bar.py
         baz.py
```

My idea would be to retain information from where the log is being generated, so for example in bar.py

```
import logging
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.addHandler(logging.NullHandler()) # Python 2.7
log.setLevel(....)
```

However I'm not sure how to call this from the frontend (which imports several bits from different packages) to display everything without hassle. For example, I'm using foo.abc and foo.xyz, set up like above for logging.  I would like to use propagation, but currently this doesn't work:

```
from foo.xyz import bar
from foo.abc import baz

log = logging.getLogger()
log.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

do_my_stuff()
```

However, no output is being generated from the library's loggers. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: So far I can get output if I get the logger corresponding to the parent module's namespace:

```
log = logging.getLogger("foo.xyz")
```

However I'm trying to grab everything in one call: I wonder if I can do that since, as I wrote earlier, this set of packages uses a namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to add a `NullHandler` to all sub-packages of `foo` - you can just add the NullHandler to the `foo` logger, which could be done in `foo/__init__.py`.

The `NullHandler` is only added to library code to handle situations where the library is used but logging isn't configured by the using application. Thomas Vander Stichele is wrong to state that adding a `NullHandler` would cause messages to be dropped.

In your application, you can configure logging as you wish - whatever handlers, levels etc. Level setting should not (in general) be done in the modules themselves, but in some central place, typically called similarly to this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    configure_logging() # whatever configuration you need to do
    main()
```

This allows REPL usage without logging being printed (other than `WARNING` or above), while logging occurs if the application is run.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you remove addHandler and setLevel from bar.py ? I don't see why you would want your package to actually do the logging instead of generating log messages, and the NullHandler sounds like it would be dropping your messages alltogether.

Comment: I merely adopted the practice from the Advanced Logging Tutorial in the Python documentation, because I would not want logging messages when I'm testing the libraries using REPL, but I would want them in the application.